# How to call API in R with a token

Tags: r, access-token, httr

i am experimenting with R and i wonder how could i GET some data from API using library httr or rcurl..

for example with curl in terminal i can do this and it gets me the data i want:

```
curl -X GET "https://some.webpage.com/api/v1/accounts/self/profile" -H "accept: application/json" -H "token-auth: 72124asfin393483feifefi92835w345"
```

note: token key is random set of chars

Unfortunately when i try to reproduce this in R i fail, i tried using something like:

```
> library(httr)
> c <- GET("https://some.webpage.com/api/v1/accounts/self/profile?token- auth=72124asfin393483feifefi92835w345"
```

or this:

```
> url = "https://some.webpage.com/api/v1/accounts/self/profile"
> key = "{72124asfin393483feifefi92835w345}"
> a <- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", key, sep = " ")))
```

Unfortunately when i try this in Rstudio i always get this error:

```
[1] "'token-auth' has to be provided for authentication."
```

More info about this particular API call:

[image: API info]

[This is the documentation](https://portal.behavee.com/api/v1/)

So i guess i obviously do something wrong with the url composition, how would i get this to work with R? I am baffled, i found some documentation on API in R, but nothing to explain how to work with a token. Thanks

Comment: Not all web APIs are the same. You would need to read the documentation for the specific API you are trying to access. Chances are good whatever API you are using does not use the Authorization header and instead expects the token to be delivered some other way. In order to get help, you need to provide some sort of reproducible example for testing. Or at least identify the specific web site rather than "webpage.com"

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I only have [this](https://portal.behavee.com/api/v1/) documentation unfortunately, i also attached a picture of the specific API GET call in the body of the question

Comment: Then try `a <- GET(url, add_headers("token-auth" = key))`. And make sure you don't have the braces in your key string.

Comment: (1) It's bad practice to name a variable `c`, likely the most frequently-used function in all of R. (Even if R is generally smart enough to use the *real* `c` most of the time.) (2) Is it a typo that you have a space in `...?token- auth=7...`? (3) In one use of token, you have just letters/numbers, but in your second use it is surrounded by braces. Is this important? (4) Last, when it says that `'token-auth' has to be provided...`, you are providing `Bearer` and not `token-auth`. Is that it?

Comment: @MrFicl Thank you, this works :) I actually tried that, but i had some typo there, therefore it did not work, so i posted my original attempt that contained Beared instead of token-authm i converted the result to data.frame and its exactly what i needed, so thanks again :)

Comment: @r2evans you are absolutely right, (1) i understand, i will name my variables better, i am learning, so i did not think about this, (2) yes, it was a typo, (3) i am not sure now, i try to follow documentation and the token is surrounded by braces there, (4) yes i see.. i actually mixed up two documentation at this point, therefore the error. Fortunately thanks to you guys it now works and i have some more information! Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct solution is what MrFlick said:

> Then try a <- GET(url, add_headers("token-auth" = key)). And make sure you don't have the braces in your key string.